# Site Title and Tagline Issue

Tags: title

Can someone please help me I am new to websites and you'll probably see it when you look at the site [Idea Saints](https://www.ideasaints.co.za) :-)

If I don't have a Site Title and Tagline [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak8UJ.jpg)there is a small white banner on top of my menu. [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv9LK.jpg)

I really want to add my Site Title and Tagline BUT when I do this [image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfT92.jpg) it makes that white banner bigger and the Site Title and Tagline are visible. [image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAF9v.jpg)

I've even gone to Elementor Settings on-page and said hide site title. [image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlUBw.jpg)At my Customize there is no option to hide it at all. [image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgTG1.jpg)

Any advice on something else I can do?

Comment: Hey, for better and quicker support you should provide your programming language :)

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean with Programming language... Like I said new to websites